# Run macro that sorts and outputs data for several sheets from master worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the list of names, and the macro code to sort and output the data. The macro runs separately for each name. I would like it to reuse the main body of the code, with the macro choosing each name, in turn, from the list

List of names:

Manny
Joe
Tom
Mike

Sort and output code for Manny:

```
Sheets("Manny").Select
Range("A2:J1000").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("Master list").Select
Range("A1:J1000").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A1:J351").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
        "Manny"
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Manny").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("H:H").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Manny").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Manny").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("H1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Manny").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:J351")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Sheets("Master list").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A1:J350").AutoFilter Field:=10
```

Comment: You mean you want to make it dynamic, and not "hardcode" the name into the macro? How do you store your list of names? A range of cells? Is there any other change that has ro be made apart from the name, like the ranges?  And also the obligatory link to [How to avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: The names can be stored on any convenient way. I can use a worksheet cell range, define a list, or any other suitable construct. Whatever works best.  Only the names are chnged, the rest of the code is the same for every name.

Answer (score 0):

Consider generalizing your process in a `Sub` or `Function` to receive the name as parameter. However, as commented see top answers of canonical question, [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1422451), where you can avoid any and all `.Select`, `.Activate`, `.Selection`, `ActiveSheet`, `.ActiveWorkbook`, and unqualified references to workbook, workhseets, columns, and cell ranges.

Below is refactored code to process sheets by input parameter name, using named range, direct assignment of range values, and `With` context block. Adjustments may be needed. Be sure to incorporate other best practices: `On Error`, `Option Explicit`, `Set object = Nothing`, etc.

```vb
Public Sub sort_data(name As String)
   Dim master_rng As Range

   Set master_rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master list").Range("$A1:J351")
   master_rng.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= name   ' USE OF INPUT PARAMETER

   With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(name)                  ' USE OF INPUT PARAMETER
       .Range("A2:J1000").ClearContents
       .Range("A1:J351").Value = master_rng.value      ' REPLACEMENT OF COPY/PASTE
       .Columns("H:H").Sort.SortFields.Clear
       .Columns("H:H").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("H1"), _
           SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

       With .Sort
          .SetRange ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(name).Range("A2:J351")
          .Header = xlNo
          .MatchCase = False
          .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
          .SortMethod = xlPinYin
          .Apply
       End With

       .Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
       .Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
   End With

   master_rng.AutoFilter Field:=10

   Set master_rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Then call above method individually or in loop for each needed name:

```vb
Call sort_data("Manny")
Call sort_data("Joe")
Call sort_data("Tom")
Call sort_data("Mike")
```

```vb
Dim nm As Variant

For Each nm in Array("Manny", "Joe", "Tom", "Mike")
    Call sort_data(nm)
Next nm
```